# List functions from within the Python's module itself

Tags: python, function, module

Is there a way I can list all functions within the module I'm in?

I don't mean to list functions from an imported module, nor methods in a class.

What I want is to list, from a function, all the other functions on the same module, i.e. identify all sibling functions.

Comment: does `dir()` get you what you're looking for?

Comment: For starters, you can use `globals()` and filter for `callable`, but that might include lots of other things too. Do you want to include imported functions too? Do you want to include any callable object or really just functions?

Comment: @a_guest thank you, this is close enough to what I need.

Comment: @Samwise not really, globals() is a better choice since it includes also the object, not only its name.

Answer (score 0):

```
from inspect import isfunction

local_functions = [obj for obj_name, obj in globals().items() if isfunction(obj)]
```

The comment from @a_guest solved my question, I needed to look at globals().
Thanks!